# Marshmallow Field not loading default value

Tags: python, marshmallow

I have a Marshmallow Schema defined as:

```
class MySchema:
    myfield = fields.Str(required=False, default=“value”)
```

When I do:

```
s = MySchema().load({})
```

I would expect the return to be:
{‘myfield’:’value’}

But I am getting {} in return.

Is there anything am I missing?

Edit:

I’m using marshmallow 3.11 due to project limitations.
I can’t upgrade to 3.15. Tried with 3.15 and it is working as expected.

Answer (score 16):

Until marshmallow 3.12:

- `default`: value to use by default when dumping (serializing)
- `missing`: value to use by default when loading (deserializing)

Since marshmallow 3.13:

- `dump_default`: value to use by default when dumping (serializing)
- `load_default`: value to use by default when loading (deserializing)

`default` / `missing` still behave the same in marshmallow 3.13+ but issue a deprecation warning.

https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changelog.html#id4

Comment: Just to clarify... Option `load_default` instructs whether to load **default value** or not. I'm having a difficult time to understand: What option sets the **default value** itself (given that `default` is deprecated)?

Comment: Answering my own question: the value set to `load_default` is the **default value** to be used (if not set, no default value applied on loading) = [documented here](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow/blob/ff3cbb124bf739104ee1e037b67a7a1d323963fa/src/marshmallow/fields.py#L85).